# I have an error: Expected lbarce at line 334, col 1

Tags: css

The first line of code is column 334. What is wrong?

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .woocommerce-account .entry-content .woocommerce{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you mean "lbrace" but there's nothing wrong there. We'd need to see more. Also, what software is generating the error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}` ?

Comment: @rpm192 Nope, doesn't have to be, it's valid CSS as it stands.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CWvnYuc -- i forgot to show the above lines. my apologies

Comment: The problem is the line above (332) is an improperly completed rule... **without braces**

Comment: Can you please educate me? I'm not familiar with css

Comment: You have a css line on line 332, which doesn't have any braces `{}`, it expects braces but gets `@media`. You need to remove line 332 or add braces after it.

Answer (score 0):

Line 332 is incomplete

[image]

```
.woocommerce-account .entry-content .woocommerce

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .woocommerce-account .entry-content .woocommerce {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

The line needs braces like so

```
 .woocommerce-account .entry-content .woocommerce {}
```

Your software couldn't find the opening left brace and told you where it expected to find it.